# How to resolve links(breadcrumb) for pages that are not part of NavigationModel

Tags: dxa

I am using DXA Web Application in java
I have internal pages that are published and accessible via links on the home page. They are not published as part of the Navigation model. Is there a way to use the existing Navigation Action to resolve breadcrumb links for these pages. 
If not, I have created a custom Navigation Controller and resolving the links in handleGetNavigation().

Answer (score 2):

All pages in the CMS are published as part of the navigation JSON, even if they are not 'visible' in the main navigation (prefixed with a number). As such it should be possible to build a breadcrumb for them (this is how it works in the .NET version at least), if not it sounds like a bug.

UPDATE: As you point out in the comment, an underscore can be added to prevent the item from being in the navigation JSON - I forgot about that. This prefix is really intended for system pages which are not displayed to the site visitor, so its not really intended for content pages, as you use it.

Comment: The structure group or pages that I use as link have "_" prefixed to its name and so I guess they are not included in the Navigation model

Comment: Can you not just remove the _?

Comment: No these pages should not appear in the navigation menu.

Comment: I have followed the below statement for displaying pages on navigation.So even though my page has no numbers prefixed and no '_' prefixed, these were shown in navigation structure.  "A naming convention is used to hide or display Pages in the navigation: sections that use a numeric prefix consisting of 3 numbers, for example 010 Articles, are displayed, sections that omit the prefix are displayed only in the breadcrumb, and sections prefixed with a underscore (_) are not visible in the navigation structure. "

Comment: Right, but isnt that exactly what you want, it to display in the breadcrumb but not the navigation? That is what a non numeric, non-underscore prefix will do... If its still showing in the navigation without the numeric prefix - its a bug

Comment: I had one page in that structure group that had the numeric prefix. I republished the _Navigation page but the breadcrumb for all these internal pages are Home/The Index

Comment: Sounds like a bug